# Only allow users to edit a specific range whilst using a 'view only' type share

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a sheet which people can copy through running a script, on the template file I want users to only see one of the sheets which contains a button that runs a script to copy the file.

I really want to share the document as a 'View Only' file although I still want the users to edit the range where the button is so that they can click on this and run the script.

I have tried protecting sheets and removing editors through Apps Script by using the class protection but this doesn't seem to work - I created the below which I had hoped would work:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  ss.getSheetByName('BALANCE SHEET').protect();
  ss.getSheetByName('LANDING SHEET').protect();
  ss.getSheetByName('CATEGORIES').protect();
  ss.getSheetByName('REMINDERS').protect();
  var user = ss.getEditors();
  ss.removeEditor(user);
  ss.addEditor('xxx@xxx.xxx');
```

does anyone have an idea of how I can do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Spreadsheet.getEditors()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geteditors) returns a **array** of [`user`s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user.html), whereas [`removeEditor`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removeeditoruser) accepts a `user`(singular) as a argument. Use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to  remove users:

```
const users = ss.getEditors();
users.forEach(user =>  ss.removeEditor(user));
```